# getFilesDir() vs getCacheDir()

Tags: android, caching, android-file

In Android you can use getFilesDir() to get a path to your internal /files/ folder, whereas getCacheDir() gets you a path to your internal /cache/ folder.

Is the only *functional* difference between these two folders the fact that Android may auto-clear some files in the cache directory if needed?

I am trying to understand the kinds of situations in which it would be a good idea to use the cache folder.

Comment: AFAIK, what you describe is the only functional difference. Note that "if needed" includes using some third-party apps that ask Android to proactively clear apps' caches.

Comment: It is possible that I try to write to the cache folder as a third party app tries to clear it?

Comment: That's an interesting question. My gut reaction is "presumably". Ideally, Android's clear-the-cache work also terminates the process of the apps whose caches are being cleared, but I don't know if that happens (and, if it did, what that means for the foreground app).

Comment: (Also I assumed internal storage meant nothing else could mess with your files -- is the cache directory the only exception to this rule?)

Comment: No apps have read, write, or delete access to internal storage, including the cache. The system has the ability to clear the cache, and third-party apps (with the proper permission IIRC) can ask the system to clear the cache. I generally assume that the system has access to internal storage, just as I assume that the Linux kernel has access to `/home/mmurphy` on my Linux machine. Statements regarding security (at least, the ones that I make) are usually with respect to other apps, not the OS itself.

Comment: "to me that is one app effectively writing/deleting on another app's turf" -- it is effectively deleting (not writing, which implies modification of content). Use cache for things that you would like to hold onto but can regenerate as needed (e.g., download it again). Don't use cache otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

getFilesDir() >>  It is used for permanent storage directory.

getCacheDir() >> Returns application specific cache directory on the file
system. The system could automatically delete files in this
directory  in some cases such as when memory is almost full.